# How do I make this infinite jquery animation end when the user is no longer hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment when you hover on any of the three items in my menu, there is a light blue dot that begins flashing red. I want that animation to stop when the user is no longer hovering over FormsItem1, FormsItem2, or FormsItem3 divs. I tried using the mouseover and mouseout functions but after I stop hovering the color changing animation seems to just arbitrarily keep going. How can I confine the color changing animations to when the user is hovering?

Here is my Jquery code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".dotIcon").animate({'opacity': '1'}, 1000);

 $('#FormsItem1').mouseover(function(){
    initList = setInterval(function dotColorChange(){
        $("#dotIcon1").animate({'background-color': 'white'}); 
        $("#dotIcon1").animate({'background-color': 'red'})
    },100); 
 }).mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
        $("#dotIcon1").animate({'background-color': 'white'})
 });

 $('#FormsItem2').mouseover(function(){
    initList = setInterval(function dotColorChange(){
        $("#dotIcon2").animate({'background-color': 'white'}); 
        $("#dotIcon2").animate({'background-color': 'red'})
    },100); 
 }).mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
        $("#dotIcon2").animate({'background-color': 'white'})
 });


 $('#FormsItem3').mouseover(function(){
    initList = setInterval(function dotColorChange(){
        $("#dotIcon3").animate({'background-color': 'white'}); 
        $("#dotIcon3").animate({'background-color': 'red'})
    },100); 
 }).mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
        $("#dotIcon3").animate({'background-color': 'white'})
 });


    $("#FormsItem1").hover(function(){
        $(".FormPreviewPane").css("background-color", "white");
        $(".PreviewContainer").animate({'top': '195px'},100);
        $("#PreviewLine").animate({'top': '77px'},200);
        }, function(){
    });


    $("#FormsItem2").hover(function(){
        $(".FormPreviewPane").css("background-color", "beige");
        $("#PreviewLine").animate({'top': '157px'},200);
        }, function(){
    });

    $("#FormsItem3").hover(function(){
        $(".FormPreviewPane").css("background-color", "lightgray");
        $("#PreviewLine").animate({'top': '237px'},200);
        }, function(){
    });

});


</script>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
<style>


.opaqueBlock{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    opacity:0.6;
    margin-left: 60px; 
    width: 360px; 
    height: 46px; 
    background-color: #486173;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.opaqueBlock:hover{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";  
    opacity:0.8;
}

.formLinkContainer{ 
    position: absolute;
}

.formTextSpan:hover + .opaqueBlock{ 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80) !important";
    opacity: 0.8 !important;
}

.formTextSpan{
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1; margin-left: 73px; 
    color: white; 
    margin-top: 7px; 
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic' !important; 
    font-size: 23px !important;
}

.dotIcon{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #D6EDFF; /*#E8F5FF*/
    position: absolute; 
    margin-left:13px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px white;
}

.dotLine{
    position: absolute;
    left: 43px;
    top: 22px;
    stroke: white;
}


img{border: none;}

.FormPreviewPane {
    position: absolute; 
    border: 1px dotted blue; 
    width: 340px; 
    height: 345px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px 5px #848C9C; 
    z-index:1; 
    background-image: url('');
    border-radius:50px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.FormPreviewPane.stuck {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

.FormPreviewPaneBackground{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 337px; 
    height: 435px; 
    z-index: 0;     
    opacity:0.15;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=15)";
}

.PreviewContainer{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 195px; 
    left: 550px; 
    width: 430px;
}

#PreviewLine{
    stroke: #D6EDFF;
    stroke-width:7;
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
    opacity: 1.0; 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -129px; top: 77px;
}

#FormsItem1{top: 250px;}
#FormsItem2{top: 330px;}
#FormsItem3{top: 410px;}


</style>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--this version works with IE-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- color change animator -->







<div id="WoodenBackgroundContainer" style="background-color: navy; height: 800px;">



<a id="PreviewContainerLink" href="" target="_blank">
    <div class="PreviewContainer">
        <svg id="PreviewLine" height="5" width="131"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
        <div class="FormPreviewPane"></div>
        <div class="FormPreviewPaneBackground"></div>
    </div>
</a>


<a href="#" target="_blank">
<div id="FormsItem1" class="formLinkContainer">
<div class="dotIcon" id="dotIcon1"></div>
<svg class="dotLine" height="5" width="17"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
<span class="formTextSpan">Internal Communication</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#" target="_blank">
<div id="FormsItem2" class="formLinkContainer">
<div class="dotIcon" id="dotIcon2"></div>
<svg class="dotLine" height="5" width="17"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
<span class="formTextSpan">Reports Package</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#" target="_blank">
<div id="FormsItem3" class="formLinkContainer">
<div class="dotIcon" id="dotIcon3"></div>
<svg class="dotLine" height="5" width="17"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
<span class="formTextSpan">Talking Points</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>



</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--this version works with IE-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- color change animator -->
<style>


.opaqueBlock{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    opacity:0.6;
    margin-left: 60px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #486173;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.opaqueBlock:hover{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    opacity:0.8;
}

.formLinkContainer{
    position: absolute;
}

.formTextSpan:hover + .opaqueBlock{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80) !important";
    opacity: 0.8 !important;
}

.formTextSpan{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; margin-left: 73px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 7px;
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic' !important;
    font-size: 23px !important;
}

.dotIcon{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #D6EDFF; /*#E8F5FF*/
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:13px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px white;
}

.dotLine{
    position: absolute;
    left: 43px;
    top: 22px;
    stroke: white;
}


img{border: none;}

.FormPreviewPane {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 340px;
    height: 345px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px 5px #848C9C;
    z-index:1;
    background-image: url('');
    border-radius:50px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.FormPreviewPane.stuck {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

.FormPreviewPaneBackground{
    position: absolute;
    width: 337px;
    height: 435px;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity:0.15;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=15)";
}

.PreviewContainer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 195px;
    left: 550px;
    width: 430px;
}

#PreviewLine{
    stroke: #D6EDFF;
    stroke-width:7;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1.0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    position: absolute;
    left: -129px; top: 77px;
}

#FormsItem1{top: 250px;}
#FormsItem2{top: 330px;}
#FormsItem3{top: 410px;}


</style>






<div id="WoodenBackgroundContainer" style="background-color: navy; height: 800px;">



<a id="PreviewContainerLink" href="" target="_blank">
    <div class="PreviewContainer">
        <svg id="PreviewLine" height="5" width="131"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
        <div class="FormPreviewPane"></div>
        <div class="FormPreviewPaneBackground"></div>
    </div>
</a>


<a href="#" target="_blank">
<div id="FormsItem1" class="formLinkContainer">
<div class="dotIcon" id="dotIcon1"></div>
<svg class="dotLine" height="5" width="17"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
<span class="formTextSpan">Internal Communication</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#" target="_blank">
<div id="FormsItem2" class="formLinkContainer">
<div class="dotIcon" id="dotIcon2"></div>
<svg class="dotLine" height="5" width="17"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
<span class="formTextSpan">Reports Package</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#" target="_blank">
<div id="FormsItem3" class="formLinkContainer">
<div class="dotIcon" id="dotIcon3"></div>
<svg class="dotLine" height="5" width="17"><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="131" y2="0"/></svg>
<span class="formTextSpan">Talking Points</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>



</div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".dotIcon").animate({'opacity': '1'}, 1000);
var initList;
 $('#FormsItem1').mouseover(function(){
   if (initList) clearInterval(initList);
    initList = setInterval(function dotColorChange(){
        $("#dotIcon1").animate({'background-color': 'white'});
        $("#dotIcon1").animate({'background-color': 'red'})
    },100);
 }).mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
        $("#dotIcon1").animate({'background-color': 'white'}).finish();
 });

 $('#FormsItem2').mouseover(function(){
   if (initList) clearInterval(initList);
    initList = setInterval(function dotColorChange(){
        $("#dotIcon2").animate({'background-color': 'white'});
        $("#dotIcon2").animate({'background-color': 'red'})
    },100);
 }).mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
        $("#dotIcon2").animate({'background-color': 'white'}).finish();
 });

 $('#FormsItem3').mouseover(function(){
   if (initList) clearInterval(initList);
    initList = setInterval(function dotColorChange(){
        $("#dotIcon3").animate({'background-color': 'white'});
        $("#dotIcon3").animate({'background-color': 'red'})
    },100);
 }).mouseout(function(){
   console.log('hei');
    clearInterval(initList);
        $("#dotIcon3").animate({'background-color': 'white'}).finish();
 });


    $("#FormsItem1").hover(function(){
        $(".FormPreviewPane").css("background-color", "white");
        $(".PreviewContainer").animate({'top': '195px'},100);
        $("#PreviewLine").animate({'top': '77px'},200);
        }, function(){
    });


    $("#FormsItem2").hover(function(){
        $(".FormPreviewPane").css("background-color", "beige");
        $("#PreviewLine").animate({'top': '157px'},200);
        }, function(){
    });

    $("#FormsItem3").hover(function(){
        $(".FormPreviewPane").css("background-color", "lightgray");
        $("#PreviewLine").animate({'top': '237px'},200);
        }, function(){
    });

});


</script>
```

When dealing with intervals, be wary of running them multiple times. Also you can call finish() to stop the animations